# VLAN Subinterface Removal - CISCO ASA

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, firewall, interface

The below are the configuration of the subinterfaces in Cisco ASA firewall and currently sub-interface 0/1.1 is only passing traffic and I need to remove 0/1.2 configuration from here as it is unused.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 no ip address

interface GigabitEthernet0/1.1
 vlan 1
 nameif vendor-1
 security-level 0
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0

interface GigabitEthernet0/1.2
 vlan 2
 nameif vendor-2
 security-level 0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
```

My question is if we run the below command, would it be fine for removing the subinterface. Will it create any issues with the other GE0/1 or Ge0/1.1 interface active traffic ?

```
no interface GigabitEthernet0/1.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly safe to remove that sub-interface. It won't interrupt traffic on the parent or other sub-interface, unless you have traffic routing between those interfaces from various hosts.